# Will it slow down the performance when Unit of work pattern is used with EF Core

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-core

I was going thru unit of work pattern, with EF Core - if the work unit is large and involves 3, 4 entities, will it slow down the performance? Because it will have to take 3, 4 db round trips and update each entity?

I've been trying to search for an answer, but did not find many links on this